# Program to Read Username and Password From Text File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

```
{
        StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter ("qasim.txt");
        a.WriteLine ("user a");
        a.WriteLine ("pass a");
        a.WriteLine ("user b");
        a.WriteLine ("pass b");
        a.Close ();
        string username = Console.ReadLine ();
        string pass = Console.ReadLine ();
        StreamReader ab = new StreamReader ("qasim.txt");

        string line1 = ab.ReadLine ();
        string line2 = ab.ReadLine ();
        //int counter1 = 0;
        //int x = 1;

        while ((line1 != null) && (line2 != null))
        {
            if ((line1 == username) && (line2 == pass))
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Welcome");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Try Again");
            }

            line1 = ab.ReadLine ();
            line2 = ab.ReadLine ();
        }
        Console.WriteLine ();


        ab.Close ();
    }
```

I have to write a program that take username and password from user and check them from the text file and if the values are correct It says "Welcome" and if the values are incorrect it says "Try Again". The problem I have in the given code is that if I enter wrong username and password the output is "try again" two times.

Comment: *'The only problem i have in the given code that i **cannot** add an else statement that says "Try Again".'*... Yes you can, do you not know how to?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek 
I tried to add else statement but because it is in a loop on entering wrong values it is giving "Try Again" two times and when I enter "user b" and "pass b" at first it gives "Try Again" and then "Welcome"

Comment: You should post what you tried, because your not using it correctly then.

Comment: can you help me I am a newbie here and in programming @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        //I am using StreamWriter here only to show//
        //the file can contain more lines//
        StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter ("qasim.txt");
        a.WriteLine ("user1");
        a.WriteLine ("@abc");
        a.WriteLine ("user2");
        a.WriteLine ("abc@");
        a.Close ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Kindly Enter Username:");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine ("Kindly Enter Password:");
        string pass = Console.ReadLine ();


        StreamReader ab = new StreamReader ("qasim.txt");
        bool userExist = false;
        string line1 = ab.ReadLine();
        string line2 = ab.ReadLine();

        while ((line1 != null) && (line2 != null))
        {
            if ((line1 == username) && (line2 == pass)) 
            {
                userExist = true;
                Console.WriteLine ("Welcome");
                break;
            } 

            line1 = ab.ReadLine ();
            line2 = ab.ReadLine ();
        }
        if (userExist == false) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Try Again");
        }


        ab.Close ();
    }
```

Now the program works program works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `Console.WriteLine("Try Again");` bellow the if.

```
{
    StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter ("qasim.txt");
    a.WriteLine ("user a");
    a.WriteLine ("pass a");
    a.WriteLine ("user b");
    a.WriteLine ("pass b");
    a.Close ();
    string username = Console.ReadLine ();
    string pass = Console.ReadLine ();
    StreamReader ab = new StreamReader ("qasim.txt");

    string line1 = ab.ReadLine ();
    string line2 = ab.ReadLine ();
    //int counter1 = 0;
    //int x = 1;

    while ((line1 != null) && (line2 != null))
    {
        if ((line1 == username) && (line2 == pass))
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Welcome");
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("Try Again");

        username = Console.ReadLine ();
        pass = Console.ReadLine ();
    }
    Console.WriteLine ();


    ab.Close ();
}
```

Or inside the else statement:

```
{
    StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter ("qasim.txt");
    a.WriteLine ("user a");
    a.WriteLine ("pass a");
    a.WriteLine ("user b");
    a.WriteLine ("pass b");
    a.Close ();
    string username = Console.ReadLine ();
    string pass = Console.ReadLine ();
    StreamReader ab = new StreamReader ("qasim.txt");

    string line1 = ab.ReadLine ();
    string line2 = ab.ReadLine ();
    //int counter1 = 0;
    //int x = 1;

    while ((line1 != null) && (line2 != null))
    {
        if ((line1 == username) && (line2 == pass))
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Welcome");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Try Again");
        }

        username = Console.ReadLine ();
        pass = Console.ReadLine ();
    }
    Console.WriteLine ();


    ab.Close ();
}
```

This way the program will ask the user he password again until the user enters the right username/pass.

Comment: I tried that but because it is in a loop on entering wrong values it is giving "Try Again" two times and when I enter "user b" and "pass b" at first it gives "Try Again" and then "Welcome".

Comment: Those lines `line1 = ab.ReadLine (); line2 = ab.ReadLine ();` inside the loop must be `username = Console.ReadLine (); pass = Console.ReadLine ();`, this way the user will be asked again until he try the right user/password. I will update my answer with it . Your second problem is how to check against all the user and password inside the text file, to do this you have two options, or you read the file to memory or read the file at each time the use guess the user and password.

Comment: The code I gave works fine and also reads all usernames and password the only problem is that it is not giving try again one time

Comment: is there any way if the username and pass are incorrect I can write try again statement outside while loop